# FOSRestBundle adding prefix to my routes

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm install FOSRestBundle in my project and configure it:

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            xml: true
            json : true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
```

In my routing.yml:

```
api:
   resource: routing_api.yml
   prefix: /api
```

routing_api.yml

```
books:
  type: rest
  resource: @ApiBundle/Controller/BookController.php
```

And BookController:

```
   //namespaces..
    /**
     * Class BookController
     * @package ApiBundle\Controller
     */
    class BookController extends BaseApiController
    {
        public function getBookAction($id)
        {
            $book = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('SiteBundle:Books\Books')->find($id);
            if(!$book)
            {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException('Book not found');
            }

            return $book;

        }



    }
```

Next i'm run console command:
`$ php app/console route:debug | grep api`
And get:

`get_book_book  GET   ANY  ANY  /api/books/{id}/book.{_format}`
So, why? 
How to configure it properly, so I got like this: `/api/books/{id}.{_format}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// routing_api.yml
books:
    type:     rest
    resource: @ApiBundle/Controller/BookController.php

get_book_book:
    pattern:  /books/{id}.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: ApiBundle:Book:myAction, _format: json }
```

Comment: yes it's works, but i don't want use `yml` for routes.